# Hawtio doesnt display Connect screen

Tags: hawtio

I'm running Windows 10 and I have installed JDK 9, Maven, IntelliJ, ActiveMQ and now I have started hawtio-app-1.5.4.jar.

When I click on any of the tabs, example "Connect" there is no content loading.
Anyone know the issue and a fix?

[image]

Comment: Can you try with JDK8

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following command to boot your hawtio-app when you use JDK 9 according to [Get Started](http://hawt.io/getstarted/index.html).

```
java --add-modules jdk.attach,java.xml.bind -jar hawtio-app-1.5.5.jar
```

By the way, hawtio 1.5.5 is already released; I recommend using the latest version.